# Can't edit files in Eclipse/Aptana?

Tags: 11.10, files

Occasionally, Eclipse/Aptana grey out opened files, making them un-editable? This has never happened to me on Archlinux or Windows - hence why I'm posting here.

Comment: What are the permissions of those opened files? Let's say they belong to root and you are trying to open then as other user...

Comment: @LnxSlck - the files are owned by me - they're editable for a while, then something happens and they become un-editable. It's strange; something I've not seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this simple solution that worked for me: 
Just press in Unity Super key, and this trick makes file writable.

Happy coding ;]

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this happen. One way of resetting eclipse is to press and hold the windows button, to bring up the search screen then release it. Now eclipse gets the proper focus and you can edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but does this maybe happen after you switched (back) to the virtual desktop with Aptana/Eclipse on it? I found that if I have Aptana Studio running on one virutal desktop, switch to another one and back to the first, sometimes Aptana doesn't get the (keyboard) focus back properly. I haven't experienced the problem in Eclipse so far, but I assume that it could happen there as well. A click on the windows title bar or a quick maximizing and restoring of the window should give it back the focus and let you edit the opened files again.

Comment: the window has focus and I can scroll through the text.. but I can't edit unless I close/re-open Aptana/Eclipse.